# tkinter, получить статус чеккбокса

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть код:

```
from tkinter import *
def get_b(event):
    if check1 == 1:
        print("Чеккбокс 1 активен")
root=Tk()
var1=IntVar()
var2=IntVar()
check1=Checkbutton(root,text=u'1 пункт',variable=var1)
check2=Checkbutton(root,text=u'2 пункт',variable=var2)
check1.pack()
check2.pack()
check1.bind('<Button-1>', get_b)

root.mainloop()
```

Подскажите как бы мне правильно получить его статус. Заранее извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же привязали переменные к чекбоксам. Через них и получаете/устанавливаете статус чекбоксов:

- `var1.get()` - получить статус первого чекбокса,
- `var1.set(v)` - установить статус первого чекбокса,
- `var2.get()` - получить статус второго чекбокса,
- `var2.set(v)` - установить статус второго чекбокса

Я в своем текущем проекте решил для себя сделать поудобнее, отнаследовался от стандартного чекбокса, и сделал, чтобы можно было получать/установить состояние проще:

```
class CheckbuttonVar(ttk.Checkbutton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._var = tk.BooleanVar()
        super().__init__(*args, variable=self._var, **kwargs)

    @property
    def is_checked(self):
        return self._var.get()

    @is_checked.setter
    def is_checked(self, value):
        self._var.set(value)
```

Пример использования:

```
# Создание как обычно
check = CheckbuttonVar(parent, text='Text')
check.pack()

# Получение/установка состояния через свойство is_checked
check.is_checked = True  # или False - установить или снять галку
print(check.is_checked)  # Напечатать статус (True или False)
```

Comment: Все сработало. Спасибо!